# In my POM structure, I get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I have used below code for importing page object in test file.

```
from pages.login.login_page import LoginPage
```

I also have `__init__` file in all folders.
still when i run test code I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages'`

```
POM
-pages
--login
---login_page.py
-tests
--login
---login_test.py
```

thats the structure of my code. My `virtualenv` is active while running test.

if I use `from Code.POM.pages.logon.login_page import LoginPage`, then it works but I don't want to use parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do that

```
POM
-__init__.py
-pages
--login
---login_page.py
-tests
--login
---login_test.py
```

in `__init__.py` file i added lines

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/Code/POM/')
```

and it started working.

> Note: each folder have `__init__.py` file but here I have shown one
>   file only in which extra code should be written.

Comment: can anyone suggest me better solution in which I do not need to write the code in `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried to follow this answer but this didn't help me. can add the exact specific solution that you applied in your solution?